# Create model class with two fat arrow functions tored in variables and default value

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want create a model class consisting of two variables (`label` and `key`) which are storing a function. Both functions need `data` as an Input object. IF you don´t specify the two functions, each of them should have an default function which is called. The default `label` function should return the input data without touching it, the `key` function should return data.uuid to get the unique ID of the data object.

This was my attempt which doesn't work...

```
export interface ListConfigModel {
 label: (data) => (data);
 key: (data) => (data._uuid);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you define this as an interface, an interface can just describe the shape, it cannot specify values.

You can either declare an interface that describes the two functions:

```
export interface IListConfigModel {
    label: (data: any) => any;
    key: (data: any) => any;
}
```

Or you can define it as a class and assign the default functions to the fields:

```
export class ListConfigModel {
    // You could specify the same types, but since we assign a value, we let the compiler figure it out.
    label = (data: any) => (data);
    key = (data: any) => (data._uuid);
}
```

Comment: on the example with the class: are the functions returning the data or data._uuid?

Comment: the default for `label` returns `data` and the default for `key` returns `data._uuid`

Comment: The signatures are the same for both, functions that takes any and return any. This is due to the fact that you did not provide more information. You could use generics to restrict these siganrtures more

Comment: thank you. The type should be any because the function should be as generic as possible.

Comment: You might consider generics, if `data` has to have a `_uuid` property, and if the type is consistent between `label` and `key` a generic approach might be : `export class ListConfigModel<T extends { _uuid: any }> { label = (data: T) => <any>data; key = (data: T) => <any>data._uuid; }`, but you know your use case best :). Don't forget to upvote and mark as answered if it was useful.